# How to put an itemize label on multiple lines?

Tags: lists, itemize, labels

I was wondering if it was possible nicely display a long label when using the itemize environment? e.g.:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item[long ugly displaying label] Stuff
    \subitem more stuff
    ...
\end{itemize}
```

The label always goes over on the left of the picture. What I thinking is to split the labels on multiple lines? Or having a limit on how far to the left of the page the label is displayed and move the "Stuff" on the next line.

Any good idea (or nice way to deal with long labels) would be nice.

Comment: The `itemize` syntax is `\item[<optional bullet character>] <item text>`, the square brackets aren't meant to contain the label, but merely the bullet (which is a circle by default, but you could use something like `$\rightarrow$` if you felt like it). In fact, the `itemize` environment doesn't cater for labels. Could you describe in a bit more detail what you're trying to achieve? Maybe the `description` environment is suited better for your task, as it typesets the label differently from the `<item text>`.

Comment: You might be interested in the `description` environment.

Comment: If you want to split the label over a few lines you could have use `\item[\begin{minipage}{2cm} long ugly displaying label \end{minipage}] stuff`. It doesn't look good, though...

Comment: @Jake `description` is really nice! Always more things in LaTeX to discover. There is only one thing missing, if there is not `Stuff` after `item`, how can I make the `subitem` start in a new line (under the label)? And it would make a good answer I think :).

Comment: @Zenon: Do you want the `subitem` to have  a leading bullet, or a bold label, or just the text?

Comment: @Jake I don't like to sound picky but it will probably depend :)

Comment: @Jake I used `description` twice now, so if you write it as an answer with some link as [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Description) I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it as ugly as you want by redefining the *itemize* lists. The labels are defined in a series of commands `\labelitemi...\labelitemiv`, which you can redefine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet\textbullet \bfseries and other ugly stuff}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash more ugly stuff}
\renewcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\renewcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
\begin{itemize}
\item First
\item second
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Ugly stuff.
      \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This will produce:

[image]

More fancy styling is possible via redefining the makelabel command and a suitable list environment as shown in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet\textbullet \bfseries and other ugly stuff}
\renewcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash more ugly stuff}
\renewcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\renewcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
\lipsum[1]
\makeatletter
\def\newitemizedenvironment#1#2{
\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{%
 \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
 \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
 \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
 \expandafter
 \list
 \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
 {\def\makelabel####1{\hspace*{150pt}\hss\llap{####1}}}%
 \fi}
 \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname=\endlist
}
\makeatother

\newitemizedenvironment{ugly}{}

\begin{ugly}
\item First
\item second
\end{ugly}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, much better. But wouldn't it be easier to just use `\begin{itemize} \item[and other ugly stuff] First \end{itemize}`, which will align the labels on the left out of the box?

Comment: @Jake I have assumed that the OP wants some permanent text printed as a label.

Comment: Ah yeah, that could be.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides this is great! But I don't want permanent labels ;).